# How can I read the strings defined in a DLGINIT structure in a .rc file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-2010

In short, how can one programatically access a compiled resource at runtime to extract strings from a `DLGINIT` structure?

A little more detailed...

In an MFC application, a Combo Box can be defined in an .rc file as a line in a dialog description using `COMBOBOX` and having a corresponding DLGINIT structure like so:

```
IDD_COMBOBOXTEST_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 200
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU |     WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "ComboBoxTest"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,209,179,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,263,179,50,14
    COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBO1,22,20,132,30,CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,22,42,132,134,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY
    PUSHBUTTON      "Load",IDC_BUTTON1,159,42,50,14
END

//...

IDD_COMBOBOXTEST_DIALOG DLGINIT
BEGIN
    IDC_COMBO1, 0x403, 4,  0    0x6e4f, 0x0065, 
    IDC_COMBO1, 0x403, 4,  0    0x7754, 0x006f, 
    0
END
```

I have learned that a Visual C++ resource file is encoded in single byte text encoding using a given code page at the top of the resource file. I've also learned that the lines in the `DLGINIT` structure are broken down as follows:

```
<CONTROL ID>, 0x403, <STRING LENGTH>, 0    <STRING BYTES ENCODED FOR CODE PAGE>
```

What I want to do is get in this compiled resource and pull out that string. There's API for some of this kind of thing using `AfxFindResourceHandle`, but I'm not sure that's the way I need to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the way the dialogs are laid out in the resource section is mirrored by how you would manually create a dialog in memory using [`DLGTEMPLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645394.aspx) and [`DLGITEMTEMPLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644997.aspx). So consult that part of the MSDN documentation to parse them. I have so far only done the inverse (i.e. created such a dialog template in memory from scratch).

There is no function to do it, you will have to do it manually.

Also, to my knowledge the `DLGINIT` isn't even stored in the PE file. I think it is merely there for the resource editor itself, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Eeek, that's disastrous. It certainly shows the age of MFC and it's roots.

Comment: @Mike Caron: it certainly is and yes, Win32 is where the MFC has it's roots. I'm just answering the question. Please turn to MS for the complaints :)

Comment: See also http://mihai-nita.net/2007/05/03/how-to-localize-an-rc-file/ for useful information.